# (Pre-installation) ownership and permissions problems (CentOS / NGINX)

Tags: installation, nginx, permissions, http-error-500, centos

This is my first time installing Magento and I feel quite stupid getting stuck so early in the proces. I followed the official documentation to install Magento 2.3 by the book.

- Fresh CentOS 7 installation on a dedicated VPS, only using root
- Using the official documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html
- Installed NGINX, configured and well
- Installed MySQL, configured and well
- Installed PHP 7.1.24 (Webtatic), configured and well
- Succesfully tested a phpinfo-page to make sure NGINX and PHP-FPM are working properly
- Created a composer project (/usr/share/nginx/html/magento2) without any problems
- Set the file permissions like described in the offical documentation
- Installed Magento without any problems
- Opened a browser. Error 500.

When I check my NGINX logs there's all kind of different permission-related PHP fatal errors like "Can't write file", "Class did not generate properly" and "Directory permission is read only". Example:

```
2018/12/20 15:08:23 [error] 16213#0: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/var/page_cache" is not writable in /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/usr...')
#1 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/usr/share/ngin...')
#2 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)
#4 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, tr" while reading response header from upstream, client: ip.ip.ip.ip, server: server.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream$
```

I chmodded the whole Magento-directory to 777 (-R), but to no avail.
I chowned from root:root to nginx:nginx, but to no avail.

When troubleshooting online I only read suggestions about apache users and www-data users, but I don't use Apache and I don't use Ubuntu.

What are the correct permissions for a pure CentOS 7 / NGINX setup?

Thanks :$

Comment: for nginx you also need to add permission for web user. default web user is www-data .
check your web user something like grep -E -i '^user|^group' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: @satyaprakashpatel Thank you for your answer. But isn't www-data a Ubutu-thing? Your command returns me user 'nginx', which I already tried. Trying to chown 'www-data' tells me that user doesn't exist.

Comment: if command returns nginx then you need to add permission for nginx user

Comment: What do you exactly mean with 'add permission'? I tried `chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2` but it didn't work.

Comment: you can set permissions as i explained in post. 
but for quick you can just run sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/var   as you hit frontend url first time so magento created few new directories  in var which is not having read write permission so if you will again try 777 then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

cd /var/www/html/[--folder_name----]/public_html && sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/ && sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/[--folder_name----]/public_html/ && sudo chown -R :apache /var/www/html/[--folder_name----]/public_html && sudo find /var/www/html/[folder_name]/public_html -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -r0 chmod 640 && sudo find /var/www/html/[--folder_name----]/public_html -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -r0 chmod 750 && sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/[--folder_name----]/public_html/{pub,var} && sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/[--folder_name----]/public_html/{app/etc,vendor} && sudo chmod 750 /var/www/html/[--folder_name----]/public_html/bin/magento && sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t var && sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t app && sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t pub && sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t generated && sudo systemctl restart httpd.service

Try this Command for CentOS 7. 
Replace this [--folder_name----] this by your folder name in html folder

Comment: Thank your for your help. It says the folder /var/www doesn't exist. I installed Magento in /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2, which is NGINX and not Apache. Is httpd still involved?

Comment: Try using /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/public_html in this command.

Answer (score 0):

First find your web user through below command

For nginx

> grep -E -i '^user|^group' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

For Apache

> grep -E -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Or

> grep -Ei '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Add one user so that you can run commands of magento through that user.
Here i am taking user name "magento"

> sudo adduser magento
>
> sudo passwd magento

Now put this "magento" user in web server group (www-data or apache or nginx)
here i am taking web server group nginx

> usermod -a -G nginx magento

Now change ownership of magento directories

> chown -R magento:nginx /full_path_of_magento_directory

you can follow 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

> After setup, always run your magento commands through magento user. Otherwise it can cause permission issues for var, generated or pub/static directories
> .

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same exact issue as OP, solution was to change SELinux permissions

After this everything was working correct

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/security.html